How to export Polygon as Polygon in a shapefile using QGIS Desktop 3.10.12
Whenever I want to export polygon layer as a shapefile 
the exported shapefile always ends up with a multipolygon geometry even when during the export I specify geometry type as polygon.

Geometry tools-> Multipart to single parts may be helpful.

Tried that. Does not help.

Shapefiles don't actually distinguish a difference between Polygon and MultiPolygon, so QGIS is incapable (short of scanning every record in the .shp file) of reporting a difference. Since a mutlipolygon could be present, that's what it reports. You can't fix this.

The ESRI Shapefile technical description states that there is no distinction between polygon / multipolygon types: there is only a "polygon" type layer which can store both multi-part geometries consisting of only one part and multi-part geometries consisting of more than one part. In fact, such "polygon" type layer is by definition a "multipolygon" layer.
